# Exception: 'Access violation reading location'

Tags: c++, exception, char, strtok

Trying to read all words from a string with a strtok(), but it returns an exception when it reaches the end and I just can't figure out why. Sorry if duplicate.

```
strcpy(now, strtok(text, del));
do {
    if (palindrome(now))
        add_list(now);
    p = strtok(NULL, del);
    strcpy(now,p);
} while (p);
```

I get this:

> `Exception thrown at 0x7C07EE43 (ucrtbased.dll) in strings.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

Comment: When the last iteration is reached, strtok(NULL, del) ; returns NULL and your code does strcpy(now, NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 issues with the code:

1. The first call to `strtok` can return `NULL`. If that happens, you should not call `strtok` again.
2. The second call to `strtok` can return `NULL`. In that case `strcpy(now,p);` will crash, since it's arguments may not be `NULL`.

Change the code to something like this (untested):

```
p = strtok(text, del);
while (p) {
    strcpy(now, p);
    if (palindrome(now))
        add_list(now);
    p = strtok(NULL, del);
}
```